# Azure Same VM name in different resource group and same vnet

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure and have very basic question. I have created following using preview portal,

VNet : test001-vnet

Resource group : test001-rg

VM in this resource group :

test-vm-001 , private Ip 10.0.0.4

test-vm-002 , private Ip 10.0.0.5

Created new Resource group : test002-rg

VM in this resource group : test-vm-001 , private Ip 10.1.0.4

logged into "test-vm-002" of Resource group "test001-rg" and did ping of "test-vm-001", it returns ip(10.1.0.4) of Resource group : test002-rg.

is this expected?. how can I differentiate same VM name in 2 different Resource Groups?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected as VMs will typically communicate via IP address. If you want to reach them via name, you will need to provide some sort of Name resolution.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/ for details and options.

Comment: I think this answer isn't complete. Azure do some kind of resolution without configuring a DNS. But in the case of the question, we should diferentiate between Azure machine name and Operating System name that usually is the same if you don't change it, and this is the main reason why there is two machines with same name in the same IP network.